# Calculate distance and move marker from origin place in google map

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps

Hi i have create a web application in which i can show distance between two place on map using google V3 api and in other web application i have created animation drop marker which i can move on the map how can i combine these two. here is my code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Direction2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Direction2" %>  
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
<head runat="server">  
     <title></title>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        var directionDisplay;
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        function initialize() {
             var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.764696, 5.526042);
             directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
             var myOptions = {
                 zoom: 14,
                 center: latlng,
                 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                 mapTypeControl: false
            };
             var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
            directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directionsPanel"));
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map,
                title: "My location"
             });
        }
        function calcRoute() {
            var start = document.getElementById("routeStart").value;
            var end = "51.764696,5.526042";
            var request = {
                origin: start,
                destination: end,
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
            };
             directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                }
            });
        }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">

    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:710px; height:300px"></div>  
    <form action="" onsubmit="calcRoute();return false;" id="routeForm">
        <input type="text" id="routeStart" value=""/>
        <input type="submit" value="Route plannen"/>

<div id="directionsPanel"></div>
    </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

And for animation i use this code:
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Drop.aspx.cs" Inherits="Drop" %>

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Drop</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var stockholm = new google.maps.LatLng(59.32522, 18.07002);
            var parliament = new google.maps.LatLng(59.327383, 18.06747);
            var marker;
            var map;

             function initialize() {
                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 13,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    center: stockholm
                };

                 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
      mapOptions);

                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    draggable: true,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    position: parliament
                });
                 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', toggleBounce);
        }

             function toggleBounce() {

                 if (marker.getAnimation() != null) {
                     marker.setAnimation(null);
                 } else {
                     marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
                }
            }
</script>

</head>
<body onload="initialize()" onunload="Gunload()">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <div id="map_canvas" style="width:525px; height:237px;">
   </div>
 </form>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for your reply geocodezip for your reply but i want to show position between two cities or country and to move move that position with marker and by changing the place by marker textbox value can also change: https://maps.google.co.in/

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Do you want to recalculate the directions when the marker is moved?

Comment: @SeainMalkin suppose i entered las vagas in startvalue textbox and new york in endvalue textbox and hit on getdirection button it will show me the direction between two cities what i want is when i move my marker from las vegas to chichago textbox text will also change according to my marker. i hope i m clear if not then let me know

Answer (score 4):

To change the name of the start or destination city when you move the marker, you need to find the start and end coordinates of the directions and use googles geocoder to find the name of the locations.

You need to listen for the 'directions_changed' event and find the start and end latlngs.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed', function() {
    var directions = this.getDirections();
    var overview_path = directions.routes[0].overview_path;
    var startingPoint = overview_path[0];
    var destination = overview_path[overview_path.length - 1];
    if (typeof startLatlng === 'undefined' || !startingPoint.equals(startLatlng)) {
        startLatlng = startingPoint;
        getLocationName(startingPoint, function(name) {
            routeStart.value = name;
        });
    }
    if (typeof endLatlng === 'undefined' || !destination.equals(endLatlng)) {
        endLatlng = destination;
        getLocationName(destination, function(name) {
            routeEnd.value = name;
        });
    }
});
```

To get the name of the markers location use the following function (I put this together quickly, will need more testing)

```
function getLocationName(latlng, callback) {
    geocoder.geocode({location: latlng}, function(result, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var i = -1;
            // find the array index of the last object with the locality type
            for (var c = 0; c < result.length; c++) {
                for (var t = 0; t < result[c].types.length; t++) {
                    if (result[c].types[t].search('locality') > -1) {
                        i = c;
                    }
                }
            }
            var locationName = result[i].address_components[0].long_name;
            callback(locationName);
        }
    });
}
```

By doing it this way, you can't set a click event to the map markers applied to the map, which means you can't have your marker bouncing animation.  If you need the marker animation, then you would have to suppress the markers in the directions service and display your own markers. When the marker is dragged you would have to recalculate the directions and then use the getLocationName function with the markers position.

[Here is a working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/SMEAD/)

Should be enough to get you closer to what you want.

**EDIT**  I've updated the code to change the value of the start or end input box when dragging.

The marker drag event will fire hundreds of times when only dragging a small distance, so we need to set a timer as not to request to many geocodes.

I've put together a working demo of this here: http://jsfiddle.net/SMEAD/6/

We needed to use our own markers so when initializing the DirectionsRenderer we need to pass in the suppressMarkers option

```
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    suppressMarkers: true
});
```

We only need to listen for directions changed once and set the markers.

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed', function() {
    var directions = this.getDirections();
    var overview_path = directions.routes[0].overview_path;
    var startingPoint = overview_path[0];
    var destination = overview_path[overview_path.length - 1];
    addMarker(startingPoint, 'start');
    addMarker(destination, 'end');
});
```

The work horse function is addMarker.  This sets up the events we need to update the input boxes and recalculate the directions.

```
function addMarker(position, type) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        draggable: true,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        map: map
    });

    marker.type = type; // probably not a good idea to do this.

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {
        var marker = this;
        clearTimeout(dragTimer);
        dragTimer = setTimeout(function() {
            getLocationName(marker.getPosition(), function(name) {
                if (marker.type === 'start') {
                    routeStart.value = name;
                } else {
                    endStart.value = name;
                }
            });
        }, 250);
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
        calcRoute(startMarker.getPosition(), endMarker.getPosition());
    });

    if (type === 'start') {
        startMarker = marker;
    } else {
        endMarker = marker;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @seain malkin but i already done that part now what i want is when i change my location in map it textbox value also change with it like i said earlier suppose i m going from new york to las vegas it will show me the direction with distance now when i drag location a to chichago it will also replicate on my textbox. can you help on this please i m stuck from past one week on this.

Comment: @amitesh Did you look at the demo? http://jsfiddle.net/SMEAD/  In the demo, type Las Vegas and New York in the input fields.  Then move the marker from Las Vegas to Chicago. The input field should update to say Chicago.

Comment: its value change in directionpanel not in routestart and routeend textbox. i want to change routestart and routeend text when drag marker in map. i hope u understand what i m trying to say if not then let know i will explain further

Comment: @amitesh Try this http://jsfiddle.net/SMEAD/1/   The problem was you are using internet explorer which doesn't support the console object.

Comment: I m using firefox mozila @seain malkin

Comment: @amitesh Oh ok, the input boxes change in firefox for me. Try it in chrome.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22174/discussion-between-seain-malkin-and-amitesh)

Comment: i made some changes in your code and it work fine thanks a lot @seain malkin can i ask u one more question if u have time