# Show near by airport on google map using javascript in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps

How can I access or show airport of interest near by area using Google Map API.

Comment: You need a database with airports and their locations and you need the user's location, then put in some logic that filters the airports in a _n_ range from the user. What is your question?

Comment: thats the main prob. i don't want to create a database i created a function to all airports and to show that i created marker but still its not working

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Places Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places)

One of the [supported place types](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types) is "airport".

Change:

```
  var request = {
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: '500',
    types: ['store']
  };
```

To:

```
  var request = {
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: '500',
    types: ['airport']
  };
```

In [this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search)

[Example with that change](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_place-search_airport.html)

Comment: i already use place library but it's not working i made a function to show airports and created marker for them but still its not working

Comment: See my example in my answer.  Use "view source" in your browser.

Comment: can i have ur mail id so that i can send to my code and tell you details so that u can help me in my project if you dont mind

Comment: view this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14080203/calculate-distance-and-move-marker-from-origin-place-in-google-map/14141454#comment19608634_14141454